# Uploading product csv error in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute, csv

When I was uploading csv I got these two errors . Any one have any idea about it ? my csv is

> https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=96cde2e067cfd3fb600a6fe212400e8f2dc9ec7b015954c9e13df329e60dbb813744b9f2db179ce26e228cc99bc7c6a5600a158559017002da05add882594b62

```
We can't find required columns: sku.

Column names: "Sku", "Highlights_internal (JB Team to incorporate into the "additional_attributes" column", "Benefits_Internal (JB Team to incorporate into the "additional_attributes" column", "Benefits Emojis_internal (JB Team to incorporate into the "additional_attributes" column", "How To Use_internal (JB Team to incorporate into the "additional_attributes" column)" are invalid
```

Comment: Make `Sku` into `sku`...lowercase. do the same for all column headers.

Comment: Please check all the column in your sheet. `Highlights_internal (JB Team to incorporate into the "additional_attributes" column` i don't think it will match in magento

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal where to match them in database ?

Comment: @Marius where I can check that in my csv all names should look like ?

Comment: In magento Admin panel > Store > Attributes > Product. Check all your `attribute_code` with column in your CSV file.. that has to be match

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you opened the file in Excel which will add a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the start of the file. When the Magento importer tries to read the file, it expects the first header/cell to say sku, but it instead sees the BOM.

Two ways to solve this:

1) Don't open it in excel - use Google sheets, or a text editor if you are feeling brave,

2) If you opened the file in excel, close it, open it in notepad++, click encoding up the top and set to "Encode in UTF-8" (NOT "Encode in UTF-8-BOM"). Then save and you are good to go.